# Laravel many entries relationship

Tags: php, database, laravel

I have a table with users and one with units, each unit can have a user. But since there are several units that can be assigned to a user, I now want to output all users with their units. However, I only get one unit per user displayed.

Unit Model

```
public function user()
{
    return $this->hasOne('App\User', 'id', 'user_id');
}
```

User Model

```
public function units()
{
    return $this->belongsTo('App\Unit', 'id', 'user_id');
}
```

User Controller

```
public function api(Request $request)
{
    $user = User::with('units')->all();

    return new UserResource($user->paginate(25);
}
```

Response:

```
"data": [
        {
            "id": 27,
            "first_name": "My",
            "last_name": "Name",
            "email": "mymail@mail.com",
            "company": "My Company",
            "active": 1,
            "comment": null,
            "created_at": "2020-09-10 06:08:04",
            "updated_at": "2020-09-10 06:08:04",
            "fullname": "My Name",
            "units": {
                "id": 21,
                "title": 21,
                "description": "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua.",
                "rented": 0,
                "active": false,
                "unit_group_id": 1,
                "user_id": 27,
                "contract_id": null,
                "subject_id": 21,
                "created_at": "2020-08-11 19:18:28",
                "updated_at": "2020-09-10 06:08:04"
            },
        }
    ],
```

There should be something like this:

```
...
"units":
[{
    "id": 20,
    "title": 20,
    "description": "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua.",
    "rented": 0,
    "active": false,
    "unit_group_id": 1,
    "user_id": 27,
    "contract_id": null,
    "subject_id": 21,
    "created_at": "2020-08-11 19:18:28",
    "updated_at": "2020-09-10 06:08:04"
},
{
    "id": 21,
    "title": 21,
    "description": "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua.",
    "rented": 0,
    "active": false,
    "unit_group_id": 1,
    "user_id": 27,
    "contract_id": null,
    "subject_id": 21,
    "created_at": "2020-08-11 19:18:28",
    "updated_at": "2020-09-10 06:08:04"
}]
```

[image]

Comment: Has you tried to replace  `hasOne` method for a `hasMany` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using one to one relationship here. While as you mentioned a user can have many units. Then its gonna be one to many relationship.
So,

User Model:

```
public function units()
{
    return $this->hasMany('App\Unit', 'id', 'user_id');
}
```

Unit Model:

```
public function user()
{
    return $this->belongsTo('App\User', 'id', 'user_id');
}
```

Comment: Sorry, this doesn't work for me. Now the unit array is empty: "units":[]

Comment: It works! I'd to remove the 'id', 'user_id'! Thanks alot!